# MassTransit CircuitBreaker

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

When using CircuitBreaker with RabbitMq like so:

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "IDocumentImported_Warehouses.Nls", ep => {
    ep.Consumer(() => _container.Resolve<DocumentConsumer>());
        ep.PrefetchCount = 1;

        ep.UseCircuitBreaker(cb => {
            cb.ResetInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            cb.ActiveThreshold = 1;
            cb.TrackingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        });
    });
});
```

The DocumentConsumer correctly does not receive further messages however MassTransit will still consume all the messages from RabbitMq and put them into the error queue. Is this expected behaviour? The documentation doesn't cover too much.

Comment: You might have more luck asking this on [the MT mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/masstransit-discuss)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are actually trying to do here, and the compact syntax isn't terribly helpful at figuring it out from the code snip. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @theMayer, "IDocumentImported_Warehouses.Nls" is a RabbitMQ queue which when messages arrive will be consumed by DocumentConsumer - when an exception is thrown in DocumentConsumer the CircuitBreaker should notice 1 exception (ActiveThreshold) and stop consuming RabbitMQ messages for 10 seconds (ResetInterval).

Answer (score 0):

I believe we cannot just stop the receiving endpoint. Circuit breaker is just a middleware, that fails proactively in case your consumer crashes over the threshold.

The meaning of circuit breaker is to allow the infrastructure behind failing consumer to recover and not get any more requests that can make it overloaded forever.

You can always consume the `Fault<DocumentMessage>` and re-publish errored messages.

P.S.
By the way, most container adapters support configuring consumers like this:

```
ep.Consumer<DocumentConsumer>(_container);
```

Comment: But surely this is how RetryIntervals work? If the consumer fails to process the message we also need to hold off taking messages from Rabbit because we can't do anything with them until the CircuitBreaker has closed? Thanks for the tip that looks a lot neater!

Comment: You can use scheduling or deferred messages. But again, the circuit breaker works exactly like it should. Imagine request-reply. Someone is waiting on the other side. We need to let them know we are failing so they can fail gracefully too. Otherwise they will keep sending us stuff.

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit introduced the ["Kill Switch"](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/killswitch.html) in version 7.1.1.

> A Kill Switch is used to prevent failing consumers from moving all the messages from the input queue to the error queue. By monitoring message consumption and tracking message successes and failures, a Kill Switch stops the receive endpoint when a trip threshold has been reached.